# Align field in openerp

Tags: python, field, odoo

How to align field at user module in openerp. fields are not properly aligning in my form. follows my code:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <!-- ===================== This is tree layout =============================-->
    <record id="lis_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Lab</field>
            <field name="model">lis.lab</field>
            <field name="arch1" type="xml">
                <tree string="name">
                    <field name = "name"/>
                    <field name = "customer_name" />
                    <field name = "excutive_name" />
                    <field name = "date_birth"/>
                    <field name = "date_delivery" />
                    <field name = "hospital_name"/>
                    <field name = "hospital_city"/>
                    <field name = "hospital_state"/>
                    <field name = "hospital_country"/>
                    <field name = "hospital_phone"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
<!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
    <record id="lis_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Lab</field>
            <field name="model">lis.lab</field>
            <field name="arch1" type="xml">
                <form string="lab" version="7.0">
                    <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                    <h1><field name="name"/></h1>
                    <group>
                        <field name = "customer_name" /> <!--on_change="on_change_customer(customer_name)"/>-->
                        <field name = "excutive_name" />
                        <field name = "date_birth"/>
                        <field name = "date_delivery" />
                        <field name = "hospital_name"/>
                        <field name = "hospital_city"/>
                        <field name = "hospital_state"/>
                        <field name = "hospital_country"/>
                        <field name = "hospital_phone"/>
                    </group>
                </form>
           </field>
        </record>
    <!-- ========================= Action Layout ============================= -->
        <record id="action_lab" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Lab</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">lis.lab</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="lis_form"/>
        </record>
    <!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
        <menuitem name = "LIS" id = "menu_lis_lab" action = "action_lab"/>
</data>
</openerp>
```

python:

from osv import osv
from osv import fields

```
class cus(osv.osv):
 _name = "lis.lab"
 _description = "This table is for keeping lab data of cord blood"
 _columns = {
 'name': fields.char('Lab Id',size=64,required=True),
 'date_birth': fields.char('Customer', size=64),
 'excutive_name': fields.char('Excutive Name', size=64),
 'date_birth': fields.date('Date of Birth'),
 'date_delivery': fields.date('Delivery Date'),
 'hospital_name': fields.char('Hospital', size=64),
 'hospital_city': fields.char('City', size=64),
 'hospital_state': fields.char('State', size=64),
 'hospital_phone': fields.char('Phone', size=64)
}
```

above codes are working fine. but these fields are randomly viewed like follow

city
customer name
lab id
executive

How can i have the same order as in xml?

Comment: View of form design in xml how that you make. You can use different form tag, sheet tag, group and div etc. You can make partition like 4 fields and value one side and other side. I don't think so fields view display randomly.If you like this than i will help you make better view compare to current view.

Comment: i need your help. how to show my application screenshot?

Comment: Take your screen shot and edit your question you can see that image tag is their below the Title, it gives you to upload your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, in your **.py** file

```
class cus(osv.osv):
_name = "lis.lab"
_description = "This table is for keeping lab data of cord blood"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Lab Id',size=64,required=True),
    'excutive_name': fields.char('Excutive Name', size=64),
    'date_birth': fields.date('Date of Birth'),
    'date_delivery': fields.date('Delivery Date'),
    'hospital_name': fields.char('Hospital', size=64),
    'hospital_city': fields.char('City', size=64),
    'hospital_state': fields.char('State', size=64),
    'hospital_phone': fields.char('Phone', size=64),
    'customer_name': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Customer Name', domain=[('customer', '=', True)]),
    'hospital_country': fields.char('Hospital Country'),
}
```

**.xml** for view file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ===================== This is tree layout =============================-->
<record id="lis_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Lab</field>
        <field name="model">lis.lab</field>
        <field name="arch1" type="xml">
            <tree string="name">
                <field name = "name"/>
                <field name = "customer_name" />
                <field name = "excutive_name" />
                <field name = "date_birth"/>
                <field name = "date_delivery" />
                <field name = "hospital_name"/>
                <field name = "hospital_city"/>
                <field name = "hospital_state"/>
                <field name = "hospital_country"/>
                <field name = "hospital_phone"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

<!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
<record id="lis_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Lab</field>
        <field name="model">lis.lab</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="lab" version="7.0">
                <sheet>
                    <group cols='4'>
                        <group>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name = "customer_name" /> <!--on_change="on_change_customer(customer_name)"/>-->
                            <field name = "excutive_name" />
                            <field name = "date_birth"/>
                            <field name = "date_delivery" />
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name = "hospital_name"/>
                            <field name = "hospital_city"/>
                            <field name = "hospital_state"/>
                            <field name = "hospital_country"/>
                            <field name = "hospital_phone"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
       </field>
    </record>

<!-- ========================= Action Layout ============================= -->
    <record id="action_lab" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Lab</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">lis.lab</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="lis_form"/>
    </record>
<!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
    <menuitem name = "LIS" id = "menu_lis_lab" action = "action_lab"/>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Hope this will now better look than your view.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working. but why should we give customer field in last in python coding. Is there any rules to format? Can you explain this?

Comment: Most welcome and it's not like that for any rule, I just copied your code and see the view, in view two field were missing. So I wrote in .py file. You can change as you want in .py file but remember, if you change filed in .xml file than it will affect on your view and please give upvote for accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have specified the xml file path in your `__openerp__.py` file under the key 'data' or 'update_xml'.
for example if your xml is inside your module's wizard folder then in the `__openerp__.py` file,

```
{
    'name': 'Module name',
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': 'its category',
    'description': """


If you install this module, then blah blah blah.
    """,
    'author': 'author name',
    'depends': ['base'],#dependent module list
    'data': ['wizard/your_xml_file.xml'],#list of xml files used in this module
    'demo': [],#list of demo xml files used in this module
    'test': [],#list of test xml files used in this module
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

Comment: which openerp python file and how?